# Append extra row to jqueryui autocomplete (even if autocomplete doesn't have any matches)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

How should an extra row be added to the jQueryUI Autocomplete results?  I've implemented [Add additional link to jquery ui autocomplete list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598098/add-additional-link-to-jquery-ui-autocomplete-list) as shown below, but it will not display the extra row if autocomplete doesn't have any matches.

What I have tried...

To append an extra row to the jQueryUI autocomplete results, I came up with the below script. The extra row is added using the following:

```
open: function( event, ui ) {
   $('<li id="add-new">Add New</li>')
   .on('click', function(event) {$("#dialog-add-new").dialog("open");})
   .appendTo('ul.ui-autocomplete');
}
```

I have three problems with my implementation:

1. If no results match the selected text, the new row isn't displayed.  Type "On" in the input and you will see it.  Type "xx" in the input and it isn't displayed. I suppose I could just have the server populate it, but seems like a waste, and would rather do it client-side.
2. Maybe problems if I have two `ul.ui-autocomplete` on the page?
3. The added row doesn't have the same appearance as the autocomplete rows.

The first item is the most critical.  How should an extra row be added to the jQueryUI Autocomplete results even if Autocomplete doesn't have any results?

Please see http://jsbin.com/quyexu/1/ for a live demo of the below script.  You could ignore the part regarding the dialog as it seems to be working.  Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Testing</title>  
        <link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
        </style> 
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            var source = [
                {value: "one",id: 1},
                {value: "two",id: 2},
                {value: "three",id: 3}
            ];
            $(function(){
                $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
                    source: source,
                    minLength: 1,
                    focus: function( event, ui ) {event.preventDefault();$(this).val( ui.item.label );},
                    select: function(event, ui) {
                        console.log(ui)
                        $(this).val('');//.blur();
                        event.preventDefault(); // cancel default behavior which updates input field
                        $("#my-list").append('<li data-id="'+ui.item.id+'">'+ui.item.value+'</li>');
                    },
                    open: function( event, ui ) {
                        console.log(event,ui,this);
                        $('<li id="add-new">Add New</li>')
                        .on('click', function(event) {$("#dialog-add-new").dialog("open");})
                        .appendTo('ul.ui-autocomplete');
                    }
                });

                $("#dialog-add-new").dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,resizable: false,height: 200,width: 380, modal: true,
                    open        : function() {},
                    buttons     : [
                        {
                            text    : 'ADD NEW',
                            "class"  : 'green wide',
                            click    : function() {
                                //Use Ajax to save value and get associated ID
                                var name=$('#new-name').val();
                                var id=123;
                                $("#my-list").append('<li data-id="'+id+'">'+name+'</li>');
                                $("#autocomplete").val('').focus();
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            text    : 'CLOSE',
                            "class"  : 'gray',
                            click    : function() {$(this).dialog("close");}
                        }
                    ]    
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="text" id="autocomplete" />
        <ul id="my-list"></ul>
        <div id="dialog-add-new" class="dialog" title="Add New">
            <form>
                <input type="text" name="new-name" id="new-name" />
            </form>
        </div>

    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: I just tried using event `response` instead of `open`, but no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add an extra row, use the response event. http://api.jqueryui.com/1.10/autocomplete/#event-response

http://jsbin.com/wokuma/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Testing</title>  
        <link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
        </style> 
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            var source = [
                {value: "one",id: 1},
                {value: "two",id: 2},
                {value: "three",id: 3}
            ];
            $(function(){
                $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
                    source: source,
                    minLength: 1,
                    focus: function( event, ui ) {event.preventDefault();$(this).val( ui.item.label );},
                    select: function(event, ui) {
                        console.log(ui)
                        $(this).val('');//.blur();
                        event.preventDefault(); // cancel default behavior which updates input field
                        if(ui.item.id===0){$("#dialog-add-new").dialog("open");}
                        else {$("#my-list").append('<li data-id="'+ui.item.id+'">'+ui.item.value+'</li>');}
                    },
                    response: function( event, ui ) {
                        console.log(event,ui,this);
                        ui.content.push({value:"Add New", id:0, label:"Add New"});
                    }
                });

                $("#dialog-add-new").dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,resizable: false,height: 200,width: 380, modal: true,
                    open        : function() {},
                    buttons     : [
                        {
                            text    : 'ADD NEW',
                            "class"  : 'green wide',
                            click    : function() {
                                //Use Ajax to save value and get associated ID
                                var name=$('#new-name').val();
                                var id=123;
                                $("#my-list").append('<li data-id="'+id+'">'+name+'</li>');
                                $("#autocomplete").val('').focus();
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            text    : 'CLOSE',
                            "class"  : 'gray',
                            click    : function() {$(this).dialog("close");}
                        }
                    ]    
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="text" id="autocomplete" />
        <ul id="my-list"></ul>
        <div id="dialog-add-new" class="dialog" title="Add New">
            <form>
                <input type="text" name="new-name" id="new-name" />
            </form>
        </div>

    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Great! you beat me to it. Had written almost the same solution.

Comment: Thanks Johny,  Had me stumped!  Any thoughts how I could style the added row?  Could I add a class to it?  If not, could I use CSS's `last-child` (without affecting other autocomplets)?

Comment: Also, my approach to determine whether I should add the row or open the dialog is a bit of a kludge.  Thoughts of a better way?

Comment: Only way I can think of is, you can give it a unique value key, like -1 or something and overwrite _renderItem function to check if ui.item.value === -1 then add styles to it. 

Made this JSFiddle a while ago > http://jsfiddle.net/e14kne1s/321/

Comment: @Johny  Yes, very similar!  Thank you.  I would have thought that I could use the `open` event to select the list, but doesn't seem to be possible.  Maybe I will create another post specific to this...

Comment: made a slight update to the fiddle, you can see the CSS is applied to the new item, works great > http://jsfiddle.net/e14kne1s/334/

Comment: Hey Johny,  Yes it does work great.  I would rather not go this far down in case future releases of jQueryUI change, however, will do so if necessary.  Thanks again!

Comment: if you find a better solution, please comment and let me know! Thanks

Comment: @Johny  I think the following is a better solution.  Use widget to assign a class to the `ul`, and then style as necessary.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29126146/1032531.  Might not have as much flexibility, but it meets my needs.  Thanks again for your earlier help.