# Using jQuery or CSS to select the jQueryUI autocomplete list

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

jQueryUI autocomplete creates a `ul` list similar to the following.  How do I select the `ul` list using jQuery or CSS?  I could do `ul.ui-autocomplete`, however, I don't want to select every list of this class on my page but just one specific one.  The IDs (i.e. `ui-id-1`) are generated by the plugin, so I can't use these.  I thought maybe the `open` event would give me access, however, doesn't appear to be the case.  `addClass()` adds the class to the `input` and not the `ul`

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content" id="ui-id-1" tabindex="0" style="display: none; width: 140px; top: 30px; left: 8px;">
   <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-2" tabindex="-1">an apple</li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-3" tabindex="-1">a peach</li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-4" tabindex="-1">an orange</li>
</ul>
```

http://jsbin.com/sovene/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Testing</title>  
        <link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(function(){
                $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
                    source: ["an apple","a peach","an orange"],
                    minLength: 1,
                    open: function( event, ui ) {
                        console.log('open',event,ui,this);
                    }
                }).addClass( "whatever" );
                $( "#autocomplete" ).on( "autocompleteopen", function( event, ui ) {console.log('autocompleteopen',event,ui,this);} );
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="text" id="autocomplete" />
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Not entirely sure I'm reading your question right - but do you want to style each individual item of the list?

Comment: @entropic  My desire is to add style to the last `li` (an orange) either using CSS's `last-child` or something similar using jQuery.  Probably is I can't get ahold of the `ul` element.

Comment: try to use css with `nth-child`, like this `.someclass ul li:nth-child(5)`, that 5 in bracket you need to change to the exact position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need it for a specific autocomplete, you can use the `_renderItem` function to override the default rendering of the control.  This passes in `ul` and `item` to it's event, where `ul` is the UL element that gets rendered, and `item` is the individual line item.

Essentially, your declaration would change to the following:

```
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: ["an apple","a peach","an orange"],
    minLength: 1,
    open: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log('open',event,ui,this);
    }
 }).data("uiAutocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
     console.log('renderItem', item);
     $(ul).addClass("whatyouneed");
     var html = "<a>" + item.label + "</a>";
     return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append(html).appendTo(ul);
 };
```

I've updated your jsbin here: http://jsbin.com/seqohugiyu/3/

As you can see, if you inspect one of the `li` elements, the parent `ul` has a class called "whatyouneed" assigned to it.

EDIT:  Similarly, if you want to grab the `ul` for the list without going through the items, you can just grab the widget portion (which will return the `ul`) and you can manipulate it anyway you want.  So to manipulate it, you would use: `$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete( "widget" ).addClass("yourclass");`

More info can be found in the documentation here: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-widget

Comment: Thanks entropic,  I was aware of this solution.  Just seems crazy that there isn't a more simple approach.  Thanks again!

Comment: @user1032531 You're right, it is a bit crazy.  I've updated the question with a MUCH simpler way to get it.

Comment: Ah, perfect!  I looked at widget earlier but didn't understand it.

Comment: This is a great solution indeed!

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS for this:

```
ul.ui-autocomplete li:last-child a {
  color:red;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ywa3jw59/)**

Comment: This will do it for every autocomplete on the page.  He noted in the question he wanted it for a specific one.

Comment: @entropic - The way I'm reading the OP's question is that he doesn't want to apply any code to all lists, which an autocomplete is comprised of. I don't think the OP means he has multiple autocompletes. But a clarification would be helpful.

Comment: I do have multiple autocompletes on the page, and thus this will not work.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: And you have nothing unique about them to identify them?

Comment: @j08691  Thank is my question.  Amazingly not (at least not until entropic posted his answer).