# Add new values to dropdown cellEditor in SlickGrid

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I want to replicate the [JQuery UI combobox](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox) with the possibility to add new choices on the fly.

The use case would be to choose from what exists already in one column, while being able to type a new value and have it added to the menu for the next cell I edit in the same column (very much like `Alt + Arrow Down` in an Excel file.

I already have the following code defining the select cell editor. The options for each column are stored as `"Option1,Option2,Option3"`string on `grid` initialization. They are stored in a global variable. How do I add the possibility to add to those options if the user inputs manually something that is not already in the list ?

```
    var SelectCellEditor = function(args) {
    var $select;
    var defaultValue;
    var scope = this;

    this.init = function() {

        if(args.column.options){
          opt_values = args.column.options.split(',');
        } else {
          opt_values ="".split(',');
        }
        option_str = "";
        for( i in opt_values ){
          v = opt_values[i];
          option_str += "<OPTION value='"+v+"'>"+v+"</OPTION>";
        }
        $select = $("<INPUT type='text' list='myoptions' tabIndex='0' class='editor-select' /><datalist id='myoptions'>"+ option_str +"</datalist>");
        $select.appendTo(args.container);
        $select.focus();
    };

    this.destroy = function() {
        $select.remove();
    };

    this.focus = function() {
        $select.focus();
    };

    this.loadValue = function(item) {
        defaultValue = item[args.column.field];
        $select.val(defaultValue);
    };

    this.serializeValue = function() {
        if(args.column.options){
          return $select.val();
        }else{
          return ($select.val() == "");
        }
    };

    this.applyValue = function(item,state) {
        item[args.column.field] = state;
    };

    this.isValueChanged = function() {
        return ($select.val() != defaultValue);
    };

    this.validate = function() {
        return {
            valid: true,
            msg: null
        };
    };

    this.init();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From a Slickgrid point of view, just making sure you've checked out the [examples](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/wiki/Examples), in the section 'Bootstrap, Dynamic Grids and Third Party component editors'. These are good templates to use as a starting point.

Your issue is, however, to do with jQueryUI Autocomplete. There should be several ways to do that through the Autocomplete API. Try [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984614/adding-values-to-jquery-autocomplete-real-time) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29122009/append-extra-row-to-jqueryui-autocomplete-even-if-autocomplete-doesnt-have-any)

Comment: Ok thank you will have a look. Isn't there an event that gives me back the value of the cell after modification so that I could check if it exists within my list of options and just add to the list there if needed ?

Comment: I know about SlickGrid but not jQueryUI Autocomplete. I think the links have the answer to that question. It depends a bit on the mechanism you use to add the value. There's a discussion of that there too.